# fs.writeFile() only saving part of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I'm creating a text editor using node-webkit. When the user clicks a "Save" menu item, I get write a plain text file to disk using the fs.writeFile() method:

```
fs.writeFile(file, txt, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("file saved");
});
```

However, it's not saving the entire string passed through the "txt" variable. It's only saving the first 300 characters or so to the file.

I've tried using this method, and the synchronous method fs.writeFileSync. Both are having the same problem. I've tried logging the txt string passed to the method to make sure there's nothing wrong there.

Any ideas why I'm not getting the full text in my saved file?

Comment: Have you tried by removing first 200 characters to save the file?

Comment: I have tried both shrinking and enlarging the string. If it's below ~300 characters, it saves the full thing. Anything over that does not.

Comment: Did you try using streams to write to a file?

Comment: Just tried it and it did the same thing:

 var stream = fs.createWriteStream(file);
 stream.once('open', function(fd) {
   stream.write(txt);
   stream.end();
 });

Comment: How is `txt` created? How is it set?

Comment: It's created by grabbing some text from a textarea using jquery: var txt = $('#editor').val();

I've tried logging the value of txt right before doing the .writeFile() above, and it looks fine.

Comment: What's the version and OS of node-webkit are you using?

Answer (score 1):

According to this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-webkit/3M-0v92o9Zs in the node-webkit Google group, it is likely an encoding issue.  Try changing the encoding.  I was having the same problem and changed my encoding to utf16le, as specified in that thread, and it fixed the issue; the whole string was written to the file.

My code is now: `fs.writeFileSync(path, data, {encoding:'utf16le'});`

Comment: P.S.  I haven't managed to find a list of all the possible encodings.  Does anyone know where that can be found?